# unable to access com component for OneNote via windows service

Tags: c#, windows, service, com

I have a console application which extracts text from images using Onenote com,when i run this application by myself it works fine but if i try to run it using windows service it gives error :
 "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {D7FAC39E-7FF1-49AA-98CF-A1DDD316337E} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"
As far as i know, it is because of not interactive nature of services. 
I even tried "Allow service to interact with desktop" option for the service but it didn't work as well.
I will really appreaciate any suggestion